# JS building up a city map

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I got this issue.

I am currently making a City Map (village) for my game, but the problem is building placing. How do I achieve this?

Now im taking for example Ikariams map as an example, testing grounds. Now this is the map itself
http://www.mmoreviews.com/imgs/Ikariam-shot-1.jpg

Now how do I place the buildings in? Getting coordinates of where the building should be and then just fit in the building.png into it or?

Comment: That all depends on how you're making your map. You could just draw them directly into it if it's just an image. Anything else and you'll have to show us what you have so far as well as what you have tried and why it failed.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information

Comment: Well currently I have the image of the map I want with like holes in and I have a bunch of buildings in .png that I want to place in.
Basically buildings should fit into the holes in the map

Comment: @TomislavNikolic So copy and paste them in? Unless you mean you want to load them dynamically. If so, start learning about [the canvas API](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/topics) and come back when you've hit a specific problem.

Comment: Well yeah thats the thing, I want to load the dynamically in a way. Lets say you own a village level 1 and in that village you have caffee level 2, it will place the correct image onto the correct coordinates. Thats the issue, I am not sure if I should just use screen coordinates to place the buildings or what

Comment: @MikeC this is an example code Im working on at the moment, but the problem is, I want to make this responsive and not to manually place buildings all the time. To make somewhat of "areas" where I could place maps in
http://pastebin.com/wVdkhFfs

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for that is using the HTML5 Canvas element. That allows you to have a background image and draw other images on it. Drawing lines, circles is quite simple as well (that can be animated with javaScript).

You need the canvas itself:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
</canvas>
```

Some CSS:

```
canvas{
            background-image: url('village.jpg');
        }
```

And some lines in your `<script>`

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var map = canvas.getContext("2d"); //main object to draw

var house=new Image();
house.src='house.jpg';
house.onload=function(){
map.drawImage(house, 80,80); //actually drawing and giving coordinates
}
```

Hope it is helpful.